# Angular - Display an Observable List by Category

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, observable

I have table of categories and item lists by category. I would like to display the list under its category. Presently trying to achieve that with an *ngIf="cat.id === mylist.catid" but not working. Any suggestion?

```
 categories: Observable<any[]>;
 myList: Observable<any[]>;


this.db.GetDatabaseState().subscribe(rdy => {
  if (rdy) {
    this.categories = this.db.getCategories();
    this.myList = this.db.getList();
}




    <div *ngFor="let cat of categories | async">
          <ion-label>
            {{ cat.CategoryName }}
          </ion-label>

    <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let mylist of myList | async">
      <ion-item *ngIf="cat.id === mylist.catid">
          <ion-label>{{mylist.Name}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
   </ion-row>

   </div>
```

Here is what Categories and MyList look like

Categories

1, 'Fruits'

2, 'Books'

myList

1, 1, 'banana'

2, 1, 'orange'

3, 2, 'Crucial Conversation'

4, 2, 'Influence'

Comment: console log the **myList** and **categories** in subscribe.

Comment: The both return all the data from the database

Comment: please post here?

Comment: Bad naming mylist with myList, although it should work in JS. Suggestion observable variable name end with $. e.g. myList$

Comment: @surendrakumar 
Categories
1, 'Fruits'
2, 'Books'


myList
1, 1, 'banana'
2, 1, 'orange'
3, 2, 'Crucial Conversation'
4, 2, 'Influence'

Comment: Can you add the getCategories function to get the clear visibility of the issue?

Comment: **CategoryName** and **id** are not there in the  myList and categories?

Comment: @surendrakumar category name is not but category id is in myList

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `SwitchMap` instead of using subscription inside `subscribe`.

```
 categories$: Observable<any[]>;
 myList$: Observable<any[]>;

this.db.GetDatabaseState().subscribe(rdy => {
 if (rdy) {
     this.categories$ = this.db.getCategories();
     this.myList = this.db.getList();
 }
}
```

Use `safe operator` in html.

```
{{ cat?.CategoryName }}
```